# I want find all records even if not yet popoulated with foreign key

Tags: sql, sqlite

Table `stock`:

```
stkid (pk), name
```

Table `share`:

```
price, quantity, stkid (fk)
```

I run this query but it shows stocks only that have records in shares already. I want to show all stocks even with no records in shares.

```
select name,
       0,
       sum(price*quantity) / sum(quantity) as avg,
       sum(quantity) as qty
from stock,
     share
where share.stkid = stock.stkid
group by (stock.stkid)
```

Comment: a foreign key only enforces that the id you enter exists in the other table, else it does nothing at all.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [LEFT JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) statement, it will still select the lines from the `stock` table even if there is no linked row in the `share` table.

```sql
SELECT
  name,
  0,
  sum(price*quantity) / sum(quantity) as avg,
  sum(quantity) as qty
FROM stock
LEFT JOIN share ON share.stkid = stock.stkid
GROUP BY stock.stkid
```

Comment: you could also add IFNULL like this IFNULL(SUM(quantity) as qty, 0)

Comment: would actually be `IFNULL(SUM(quantity), 0) as qty`

Comment: thank you guys I used IFNULL to get results as 0s instead of empty values